# Extremely slow performance of hide/show function when dealing with large number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome, safari

I am experiencing terrible performance when I'm doing $("#myDiv").show() and $("#myDiv").hide() only in Safari and Chrome on a Mac, all other browsers including IE6 are working fine on PC and Mac, so this is a Webkit issue.

The div "myDiv" contains a large number of elements, including lots of checkboxes, JqueryUI tabs, and 3 sliders.

I tried "addClass" instead of show/hide, I tried setting margin to -10000 and back to 0 and none of these things seem to help. Is there a work around or is this a limitation of these browsers?

Comment: Perhaps it could be a jQuery issue? Try using classic javascript and see if it has any effect. `document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'none'`

Comment: How did you determine that `.show()` and `.hide()` are causing the slowness?

Comment: Just saying, that kind of stuff usually runs faster for me in webkit than the others. o.O

Comment: On a mac? This is a mac specific issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I do apologize for this, but this is mind blowing....

After solid 50 JS tweaks with no avail, it turns out that my problem was in CSS!!!

After wasting a day on this, turns out that "background-size: 100%;" crashes webkit! That's insane... Removing that one line removed all of my crashes.

Again, very sorry for reporting the wrong issue.

Comment: Urg. I had this too (Chrome and Safari latests on Windows 7, if that matters). The browsers were really slow performing most jQuery animations, whereas Fx, IE and Opera were all fine and I had no idea why. Turing off `background-size: auto 100%;` solved it. Thanks for posting this (rather frustrating) solution.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be an issue already discussed [Jquery hide() and show() runs too slow in google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840891/jquery-hide-and-show-runs-too-slow-in-google-chrome). They determined it was a bug in chrome.

Comment: I did see that but it doesn't give a workaround. Also, Safari has the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$("#myDiv").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: I did, makes absolutely no difference

Comment: Very strange. Normally WebKit performs very good with large number of dom nodes.

Answer (score 4):

Try caching your myDiv by doing `var $mydiv = $('#myDiv')` and in your selector just use `$myDiv`. This will avoid creating a jQuery object every time you want to show or hide.

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't help at all :(