# How to remove a particular CSS style for Safari 5.x Windows?

Tags: jquery, css, safari

Okay, so long story short, I've been having terrible jQuery performance issues under Safari 5.x for Windows; and [it turns out it's related to the `background-size` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555762/extremely-slow-performance-of-hide-show-function-when-dealing-with-large-number).

Just like the answer to that question suggests, removing it does increase performance significantly (except I was using `background-size:cover`).

I need this CSS property to make the website look aesthetically pleasing, so is there some method where I can disable this property just for Safari 5.x Windows, or is there another way of duplicating the effect `background-size:cover` has?

Comment: Include an image element as the background instead, and set it to 100% size, that somewhat duplicates the "cover" effect and works everywhere.

Comment: What is possible for backgrounds with `background-size: cover;` will be possible for images/videos, too. The property is called `object-fit: [contain | fill | cover | none];`. The browser support is nearly _non-existent_: http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'm thinking of is browser hacks, but it is probably not the best way to do it...
You can use the javascript given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser) to detect the browser and its version, and this code to detect if the operating system is Windows: `navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1`

Then, you can select the css stylesheet you want to use depending on the previous results: write a css with the `background-size:cover` for every browsers except Safari 5/Windows, and another one without it for this particular browser. But as I said, it's more like a hack than a real solution...