# jQuery functions don't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, show-hide

I did this call in Javascript in IE and it works great but in Chrome NOT at all!

I want to hide or show table rows according to a boolean evaluation.

```
function show(checked, tableName) {
    if (checked) {
        $(tableName + " tr.class1").show();
    } else {
        $(tableName + " tr.class1").hide();
    }
}
```

> **IN HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="show(this.checked, '#tbody1')" />

<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody id="#tbody1">
<tr class="class1"><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr class="class1"><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: What does `tableName` hold

Comment: The most likely cause of this is that `tablename` does not hold a proper jQuery selector.

Comment: this seems to be an issue in chrome
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840891/jquery-hide-and-show-runs-too-slow-in-google-chrome

Comment: @Sushanth--. I've changed the question for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Foolish problem! It works now! It was a problem of Chrome temporary files. It was running the previous version of my javascript which was an include!. Thank you all you guys for the time.

Answer (score 0):

This script I wrote works for me:

```
var tableClass = '.table';

var checked = false;



if(checked){

    $(tableClass + " tr.class1").show();

}else{

    $(tableClass + " tr.class1").hide();

}
```

Having this html:

```
<table class='table' border="1">

    <tr class='class1'>

        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>

        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>

        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, as I said in my answer, it was a problem of cache! Thanks for the answer.